# Mongo Get unique field value from large query

Tags: database, mongodb, performance

In order to populate a cache I need to query all the clubs that have already sold tickets within a time span. So I query all tickets sold and loop through all of them to find the active club list of a given period. But this if a heavy computation that runs nearly every minute on a large number of tickets, so it is impacting my infrastructure bill.
How can I make a more efficient query?

Document

```
{   
    id: "32r34r34r3r434r4r", 
    creationDate: 18909894344,
    clubId: "9685ut56tu9t698t9",
    type:"TICKET"
}
```

Collection

```
...
{clubId: "3e32e4r43r43r43r4",...},
{clubId: "3e32e4r43r43r43r4",...},
{clubId: "5t89u54u895tu95t8",...},
{clubId: "6t68ut986ut986ut9",...},
....
```

I need to get

```
[
"3e32e4r43r43r43r4"
"5t89u54u895tu95t8"
"6t68ut986ut986ut9"
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can u try with this

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{
$group:{
    _id:null,
    clubIds:{$addToSet:"$clubId"}
    }
}
])
```

Comment: my structure is flat. each document has a clubId field.

Comment: Answer updated. Can u try with this. Did'nt understand `Query ` specified in the question

Comment: typo. I meant collection

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a query to [`distinct`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/#db.collection.distinct) to do this:

```
db.collection.distinct('clubId', query)
```